# What are the advantages of using Microsoft Workflow Foundations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, workflow-foundation, graph-databases, arangodb

I have an investor who is very keen on basing our workflow and database on Microsoft Work Flow Foundations.

However, I have already built an interactive graph-database in Javascript, Node.Js and ArangoDB, that works exactly the way I want it to.

I have no experience in .NET, Microsoft Technology, or Visual Studio. Is difficult to learn?

What are the advantages and disadvantages I should be aware of in terms of fx. scalability, flexibility, and the possibility of building extensions in other languages than .NET?

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience I can tell you that if you have a team (which you most probably hired to be..) experienced in technology `A` and then half ways done switching to a completely unrelated technology `B`, this will give you definitely a loss of productivity, and maybe team members not willing to adopt to the new environment that will drop out of your team (in the end you make them drop their experience and start over at junior level).

I have been in such a situation several times, once PHP/Perl/C -> Java, once PHP/JS/CSS -> C#+webforms, once C++ -> Java+Weblogic, so I know what I'm talking about.

You should plan a workshop where you hire a trainer experienced with the technology, that explains it to you and your team. In that workshop you should start to implement samples in training sessions. Best case the trainer should stay available for some weeks to aid the transition. You need to closely monitor the mood of your people, and work with goodies like merchandizing and food to keep the situation under control.

You should calculate the costs of such a transition and estimate the possible loss of productivity and team members including hiring somebody to replace them to your investor.

Reading through the documentation of [Worflow Foundtations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx), you would probably use the C# ArangoDB driver.

Comment: I've just finished training a team on WWF.  
It is quite a big jump for developers to understand because it is somewhat procedural rather than OO.
It is very hard to learn on your own.  It has much in it that is quite obscure.  
Over the years I've broken it down into the simplest system I can and that makes it much easier to follow.